# Params for WebCrawler in crawler4j

Tags: java, crawler4j

Is it possible to pass params to WebCrawler ?
For example I want to pass new rule for `WebCrawler.shouldVisit(WebURL url)` method in runtime or set some field in my WebCrawler. 
Is it possible?

Comment: I found the answer.
You can use method CrawlController.setCustomData(Object customData) to store data and than you can fetch your data from crawler by using WebCrawler.getMyController().getCustomData()

Comment: Great! Add it as an answer yourself, and after a while (I believe 2 days) you will be able to mark it as the correct answer. See the help center - this is a perfectly normal thing to do.

Comment: I've tried but I can't do this during first 8 hours, I will move this to answer asap.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the answer. You can use method CrawlController.setCustomData(Object customData) to store data and than you can fetch your data from crawler by using WebCrawler.getMyController().getCustomData().